# Change a buttons css using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a hidden button i want to show when the user has 5 coffee this is my code but it just doesn't seem to work

**JS**

```
window.setInterval(function(){

                   if (coffee == 5) {
                   document.getElementById("U1").style.visibility = "visible";
                   console.log()
                   }

                   }, 500);
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="U1" onclick="SuperPlant()"> Super Beans</button><br>
```

**CSS**

```
.U1 {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

**ERROR IN CONSOLE**

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("U1").style')
```

Comment: You are using a `class` but selecting the element using id method so either you need to declare an id to the button or you need to use `getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your `setInterval()` command, and it doesn't need to be inside of a function. Like this:

```
window.setInterval("if (coffee == 5) { document.getElementById('U1').style.visibility = 'visible'; console.log() }", 500);
```

NOT THIS:

```
window.setInterval(function() {if (coffee == 5) { document.getElementById("U1").style.visibility = "visible"; console.log() } }, 500);
```

Also your button should have `id="U1"` NOT `class="U1"`. Which means change CSS selector to `#U1`.

Comment: When i do that i get SyntaxError: Function statements must have a name. and if i format it i get the error UNEXPECTED EOF

Comment: Yes, you do not have an element with an ID of "U1". As I stated in my answer above, you need to change your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML :

```
<button id="U1" onclick="SuperPlant()"> Super Beans</button><br>
```

AND CSS:

```
#U1 {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This is because you are using getElementById(); and your button where only named by class, and not ID.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do it as follows:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5kpb5gxb/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<button id="U1" onclick="SuperPlant()" style="visibility: hidden">Super Beans</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var coffee = 5;

function showButton() {

    if (coffee == 5) {
        document.getElementById("U1").style.visibility = "visible";
        console.log()
    }

}

window.setInterval(showButton, 500);
```

I would recommend against the anonymous function in the `setInterval` as it can be hard to troubleshoot.

Hope this Helps.